# SharePoint Ribbon TrimById not found

Tags: web-part, ribbon

I want to hide some parts of my ribbons. I'm working with SharePoint 2013 I created a WebPart:

```
        SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        if (ribbon != null)
        {
            ribbon.TrimById("Ribbon.Library.CustomViews");
        }
```

Visual Studio Error Message: TrimById method is not found.

How can i hide buttons in the SharePoint ribbon?

Comment: Did not you think to use CSS to hide buttons?

Comment: I need to hide the ribbon only for a group of users. Can i do that with CSS ?

Comment: Try this `div#suiteBar {display: none;}`

Comment: How can i hide my ribbon by users group with CSS ?

Comment: Check here how to get groups and users by js http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185012(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Remember to hide in ECB aswell. (Edit Control Block)

Comment: Why not use the CustomAction? You can specify permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

as far as your error is concern, you must be missing assembly reference of `Microsoft.Web.CommandUI`.

for hiding button, you can try the following code. This will hide library tool tab from your document library

```
public void HideRibbonButton()
    {
    //if this is a System.Web.UI.Page
    SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this);
    ribbon.TrimById(“Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Actions.DeleteItem”);

}
```

[Source](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/24/hide-ribbon-buttons-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/)

Comment: What is the difference in this code and the OPs code?

Comment: Robert don't you see the parameters in TrimByID?

Comment: I see you are aiming for different sections, but no explanation why :)

Comment: he has asked the question of hiding buttons.as far as his error is concern, he must be missing assembly reference of Microsoft.Web.CommandUI

Comment: Then isn't that somethig to add to your answer?

Comment: ok. I have updated my answer.hopefully no negative this time.

Comment: Don't take it that way, I was just trying to make your answer more helful (giving the OP a chance to get his problem solved, and you a chance of earning some nice reps)

Comment: :) I don't mind you putting negative.but once I update/improve my answer, I expect you to remove negatives.if its incorrect, I don't mind you putting me infinite negatives. ;)

Comment: sometimes, questioner may ignore negative votes answers, that's what I am trying to say. I am not running after reps

Comment: Understand your point, but this answer has not gotten any downvotes, nor upvotes

Comment: I am pointing to some other thread.